# difference between empty HashSet class and Object type HashSet class

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
HashSet<Object> hashset = new HashSet<Object>();
```

and

```
HashSet hashset = new HashSet<>();
```

I have some clarification regarding this, i know that Hashset can hold heterogeneous data type, but i am not sure about the other one